# Using the midpoint rule to show that the definite integral of f(x)=x^2 on [0,1] is 1/3

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I have a question that asks the following

> Let $f(x)=x^2$ on [0,1]. If we use the midpoint rule $M_n$ with $n$ subintervals of width $\Delta x= \frac{1}{n}$ so that $$M_n= lim_{n\to∞}\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta xf(\frac{(i-1) \Delta x + i \Delta x } {2} )= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \frac {(\frac {i}{n} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac {i}{n})^2} {4} $$ show that $\lim_{n\to∞} M_n= \frac{1}{3}$.

I have attached a picture of my work so far and am unable to further simplify to get the desired answer of $\frac{1}{3}$. Any help appreciated! [image]

Comment: You could use $$(x+1)^3-x^3=3(x^2+x+\frac14)+1-\frac34=3(x+\frac12)^2+\frac14$$ to transform the present sum into (the sum of) a much more simple sum and a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)^2=4\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 -4\sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^n 1=\frac{2}{3}n(n+1)(2n+1)-2n(n+1)+n$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}n^3-\frac{1}{3}n$$
Now dividing by $4n^3$ gives
$$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{12n^2}.$$
Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ gives $\frac{1}{3}$.